# Need help on django urls

Tags: django, django-forms

How to validate the url if some change the name in url and  update  the form,

Suppose :
If i want to update a profile ,after click on the update button.ulr link will be like below

url : http://localhost:8000/profile_edit/sushanth/

i found there is an security loop here,a person can change the name on the url and he can edit other person profile,how to close this loop hole while updating the form in django.

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check in your view that the user is the correct one.

```
@login_required
def profile_edit(request, username):
    if username != request.user.username:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed()
```

Comment: Here i am not using django authentication,using remote.meta.get('Remote_user') as logged in user for my app.

Comment: got it,thanks for the quick response.i have another question how to put a condition who has access to edit all the profiles in the similar passion...

Comment: then change the condition to if username != remote.meta.get("Remote_user").

Comment: i did the same and it worked.how about a privileged user have access to  edit muitple profiles and if the change the name on the url and edit.how to restrict ....